# Download Manager with Tor

Tags: add-on

I would like to know if it's possible to integrate a download manager
with Tor ?
I use Free Download Manager and i want to know if i can change something
in the parameters of Tor to do it possible ?
If it's possible, someone can explain me how ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For someone reading in 2023:

Free Download Manager now support Socks5 proxy. To access onion download links, just **run a Tor Browser** and then add Address: **127.0.0.1** and Port: **9150** in your FDM settings:

[image]

After that you can paste onion download links in FDM and it will use socks5 proxy to download files.

Disclaimer: I have zero knowledge of Tor and Proxies, I just found this method while messing with tor settings and FDM settings. I am not sure if this is safe or anonymous. I am sharing because it works, but I dont know at what cost. Someone experienced can probably provide input if this method is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Tor is JUST a SOCKS proxy - so make it set into the download manager's settings and you're good to go! A separate remark if you're about to use a download manager from dot-onion sites: make sure they're properly **locally** resolved and routed to Tor's TransPort

Answer (score 0):

As I've searched [HERE](https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/blog/?p=468), currently FDM does not support SOCKs proxy and it is their TODO list. Therefore you should use some external applications for tunneling the system traffic through TOR (or a specific program) such as [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/). You can run TOR browser in order to run the SOCKs proxy on your system, then add the proxy server to Proxifier as below.
[image: Proxifier Server Setting].

Then you can add a rule to tunnel FDM traffic through the proxy, as below:
[image: Proxifier Rules]

However, Proxifier is not free. You can see list of alternative programs in [this link](https://alternativeto.net/software/proxifier/).